# Messages not received on master when the talker runs from startup

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bash, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a detection node acting as a talker (`det_talker.py`) on one Ubuntu 16.04 machine and another node acting as a listener (`det_listener.py`). I intend to run the listener on master (an Ubuntu 14.04 machine) to receive the messages being sent from the talker. When I run the talker from a terminal followed by the listener on the master, I can see the messages being received on the master.

However, when I run the same talker node by putting the necessary commands for sourcing the setup.bash file as well as configuring the IP for the master in a bash script and run this script from startup (by adding the script in *Startup Applications*), I cannot see any messages on the master.

Configuration on the machine with the talker node:

- ROS_MASTER_URI = http://ubuntu14_ip:11311
- ROS_IP = ubuntu16_ip

Configuration on the machine which acts as master:

- ROS_MASTER_URI = http://ubuntu14_ip:11311
- ROS_IP = ubuntu14_ip

I have tried changing the ROS_IP on master to ubuntu16_ip but the result is still the same.
The script I am using to run the detection node from system startup looks like follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/rahul
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http://ubuntu14_ip:11311
source ./catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
cd catkin_ws
rosrun detection_node det_talker.py
```

I have tried running this bash script from a terminal; it runs successfully and I can see the messages on master when I run the det_listener.py node. Only when I run it from startup, there are no messages (the node does run, however).

Furthermore, I can see on the master that the node is running because it shows the node when I run `rosnode list` and `rostopic list` commands. I should also mention that Ubuntu 16 has Kinetic and Ubuntu 14 is running an Indigo version of ROS. The reason why I think different versions should not pose a problem because I can indeed get the messages when executing the node from terminal.

My question is how do I get the messages to be received on the master by running the talker from startup.
Thanks.

Edit: A cross-post on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51152064/messages-not-received-on-master-when-the-talker-runs-from-startup).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296046/messages-not-received-on-master-when-the-talker-runs-from-startup/) by [rahul_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/35030/rahul_b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added the IP and name of the master (ubuntu14) in */etc/hosts* file on the node machine (ubuntu16) and vice versa. When I restarted both machines and ran the node again from startup, I can receive the messages on the master.

A side note: If someone (like me) is trying to do a similar task with run multiple nodes, make sure to add the IPs and names of all the nodes in */etc/hosts* of the master AND that all the nodes have distinct names since it is not possible for the master to resolve between nodes having same names.

---

Originally posted by [rahul_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/35030/rahul_b/) with karma: 16 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0